# Nginx reverse proxy into external cPanel server results in an error

Tags: cpanel, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to reverse proxy into a cPanel account by attempting to use the following Nginx configuration (`123.123.123.123` is the cPanel IP), but I'm getting an error: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

```
server {
server_name example.com

        access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

        location / {
                    proxy_pass http://123.123.123.123;

  }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
server_name example.com

        access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

The following is returned by curl:

`curl --head https://example.com/`

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Mon, 04 Oct 2021 20:59:17 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
x-redirect-by: WordPress
location: https://example.com/
x-litespeed-cache: hit
```

`curl --head http://example.com --resolve example.com:80:123.123.123.123`

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Mon, 04 Oct 2021 20:59:33 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://example.com/
```

The only thing I can find on the topic is:  [cPanel powered site is not accessible via IP address by my reverse proxy (it gives a 404 error)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/126039/cpanel-powered-site-is-not-accessible-via-ip-address-by-my-reverse-proxy-it-giv) Could it be the same issue of a header being required?

Loading `http://123.123.123.123` does open the site by the way.

**Update:**

By adding the following to: */etc/hosts*

```
123.123.123.123 example.com www.example.com
```

and then changing `proxy_pass` to:

```
proxy_pass https://example.com:443;
```

I now see the following not found error that cPanel returns:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps try setting [proxy_pass](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) to use port `443` (`proxy_pass https://123.123.123.123:443`), since I assume you want to proxy an HTTPS site on your cPanel server. Proxying port `80` might lead to redirect errors if that's being redirected in the cPanel server (by WordPress for example), which appears is the case based on your curl output since you're being `301` redirected to the HTTPS protocol.

Comment: Are you using this ngnix reverse proxy to add the SSL certificate?  If so, why not just configure letsencrypt using cPanel and skip the reverse proxy?

Comment: I made some progress it seems by modifying /etc/hosts with ```123.123.123.123 example.com``` and then changing the proxy_pass address to ```proxy_pass https://example.com:443``` but now I get the page not found error cPanel gives out https://i.gyazo.com/a2bfecb59b559a51c6670607858fa959.png

Comment: It seems that using port `443` for `proxy_pass` solved the original problem regarding "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS". I'm not sure why you modified the hosts file though and didn't just use the IP as in my comment, and then pass the host using [proxy_set_header](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/). That would allow Apache in cPanel to direct incoming requests to the correct [virtual host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html).

Comment: Since cPanel manages [virtual hosts](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/cpanel-product/how-your-server-handles-domains-and-virtual-hosts/) for you, you'll need to make sure a [domain](https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/domains/domains/) or [add-on domain](https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/domains/addon-domains/) is setup for that host.

Comment: What is the output from `curl --head https://example.com --resolve example.com:443:123.123.123.123`?

Answer (score 1):

Your origin server isn't properly configured.  It is returning a redirect to HTTPS and isn't actually configured to server the site over HTTPS.  You need to either:

- Configure your origin server to serve the site over HTTP rather than redirecting to HTTPS.
- Configure your origin server to server the site over HTTPS rather than showing the default cPanel page.

The problem is not with your reverse proxy server.  The problem is that there doesn't appear to be a way to get the content from your origin server.

You might want to take a step back and evaluate whether or not you actually need to use a reverse proxy server at all.  It appears to be adding HTTPS certificates and forwarding requests to an IP address.  If that IP address is public and that machine can be configured with LetsEncrypt, I would suggest skipping the reverse proxy altogether.  Reverse proxies always reduce performance by a little bit and should be avoided if possible.